# XForms trigger being activated by another input element

Tags: xforms

I've got a button at the top of the page like this which is an initial submission:

```
<xf:trigger>
 <xf:label>Submit</xf:label>
 <xf:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
   <xf:setvalue ref="instance('query')/start" value="5"/>                 
   <xf:send submission="submit"/>
 </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
```

And an input field like this which is supposed to set a different value for "start" and then resubmit:

```
<xf:input ref="instance('query')/start" incremental="true">
  <xf:label>Start Index: </xf:label>
  <xf:send submission="submit"/>
</xf:input>
```

I would like the input field to send the submission when I press enter but it appears that pressing enter only dispatches an event which the actions in the trigger listen to.  I thought actions within the trigger element are isolated to the trigger.  I've actually found a work-around by creating a trigger before this one that only contains the send element.  Only the first trigger in the document is activated by the input element.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `ev:event='DOMActivate'` attribute on the second `xf:send` action?

Comment: Perhaps.  I think its the default behavior, at least in Betterforms.  I've tried every combination of adding and removing ev:event='DOMActivate' and wrapping and unwrapping action elements around the individual actions.  It always behaves the same.  Pressing 'enter' within an input field triggers the first button in the document but not itself.  Its really quirky.  I've even been trying to specify ev:observer with no luck.

Comment: I haven't used betterFORM extensively, but have you tried using separate `xf:dispatch` elements, within each control, to send an `xforms-submit` event to your model, instead of using `xf:send`? If you can provide a complete form, I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: Not very familiar with betterFORM here but 1) "I thought actions within the trigger element are isolated to the trigger": Yes, that should be the case per the XForms spec, although keep in mind that DOM events bubble. 2) You are missing an `ev:event` attribute on the second `xf:send`, although maybe betterFORM has a notion of default event (that's not in the XForms spec for sure).